# CPU/IO/RAM/Network monitoring in system tray for Kubuntu

Tags: linux

I am looking for an application that adds CPU/IO/RAM/Network monitoring in the system tray and works with Kubuntu.

E.g. on Mac OS X I use [MenuMeters](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add plasma widgets to your panel, next to the system tray.
Here is mine (I'm using Plasma 4 but I think they are also present in the new Plasma 5):

[image: The monitor widgets]

The widgets are:

- CPU Monitor
- Memory Status
- Network Monitor

---

To add plasma widgets to your panel:

[image]

Then select which widget you want to add:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I wish that clicking on the widgets would display more details.